# Increment string in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, increment

i am using a video with a simple background and prompting an alert text whenever someone passes by.

```
clear all

myVideoObj = VideoReader('video.avi');

nFrames = myVideoObj.NumberOfFrames;
sound = wavread('somethingwrong.wav');
flag = 1;

% Read one frame at a time.
for i = 2 : nFrames-1
    frame1 = read(myVideoObj, i-1); frame2 = read(myVideoObj, i);
    diff = abs(rgb2gray(frame1) - rgb2gray(frame2));

    if sum(sum(diff)) < 46000
        imshow(frame2, [])
        drawnow
    else 
        imshow(frame2, [])
        text(100, 100, 'Intruder!!!' , 'FontSize',24)
        drawnow
    end
end
```

The drawon works. But now im trying to figure out how to do an increment of strings for each person that passes by. How do i start? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make it so the text increments a counter each time it detects an intruder (so this is included in the "Intruder!!!" message)? If so, you should be able to accomplish this as follows:

You can make a string variable and a counter:

```
message_string = 'Intruder #';
count = 1;
```

and then each time you find a new person, you would set a new message string:

```
total_message = strcat(message_string, num2str(count));
```

which would be sent to the text function:

```
text(100, 100, total_message, 'FontSize', 24)
```

then increment the count.

If this is not an answer to your question, please clarify what you mean by doing an increment of strings for each person that passes by.